# TRIGGERS FOR AUTO-INCREMENT

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sequence, auto-increment

I have a Vehicle Table whose Primary key Vehicle_No is of Varchar2 Type so i made a trigger for auto increment but it shows errors

```
create sequence seq start with 1000 increment by 1;

create   or replace trigger vehicles
Before  Insert On Vehicle
For  Each Row
If (:New.Vehicle_No is NULL)
Then
Select seq.nextval INTO :New.Vehicle_No from dual;
End if;
End;
```

Comment: *"it shows errors"* is not very helpful to us. We don't even know whether these are compilation or runtime errors (we don't have access to your schema so we can't build or run your code). Please include the error stack in your question. If these are compilation errors you can use `select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'VEHICLES'` to list them.

Answer (score 1):

Missing parts in syntax (`begin`); should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER vehicles
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON Vehicle
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :New.Vehicle_No IS NULL
   THEN
      SELECT seq.NEXTVAL INTO :New.Vehicle_No FROM DUAL;
   END IF;
END;
```

Apart from that, it seems to be OK. Though, if you're using a sequence (which is a `number`), why is the primary key column `varchar2`?